# Accept your own answer give you points even if you accept another answer 2s after

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I think there is a little bug in SE interface: I just accepted my own answer for a old question in TeX.SE and then, 2s after, changed my mind and accept another answer. The system give me +2 of reputation and never take it back...

Comment: Not a bug, the +2 was because you accepted the other answer. Accepting own answer gives no reputation.

Comment: I don't follow. You got 2 rep for the accept of the other answer. Why would it be taken off?

Comment: Also, nice view can be seen [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/166635/timeline)

Comment: Ok my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you accept an answer from someone else you get a +2 to your reputation.

If you accept your own answer you don't get any reputation increase.

What you are seeing is perfectly normal:

1. You accept your own answer - no reputation increase.
2. You accept someone else's answer - the tick moves and you get +2.

All perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on the helppage:

You gain reputation when:
answer is marked “accepted”: +15 **(+2 to acceptor)**

So when you accepted your own answer you did not gain any rep but when you accepted the other answer you gained the 2 reputation as normal.